# Android LogCat is showing old logs

Tags: android, logging, logcat

LogCat in Android Studio is showing me only the logs from about a day ago, while "adb logcat" command and DDMS LogCat window, works ok!

What I have tried: removed just about anything android related (except projects) and reinstall everything.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot believe it. The solution to this problem was to reboot my phone.